# Identity function with perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11, forwarding

I want to write a function `identity` which perfectly forwards its argument without any copy. I would write something like this

```
 template< typename V >
 inline V&& identity( V&& v )
 {
   return std::forward< V >( v );
 }
```

But is it correct? Does it return always the correct type? Does it simply forward `v` independently if it is a lvalue/lvalue reference/temporary?

Comment: As long as you don't call it explicitly with "incorrect" type (as `identity<const int&>(42)`), it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a parameter pack as a guard, so that nobody can actually force a type that is different from the one that would have been deduced otherwise.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename..., typename V>
constexpr V&& identity(V&& v) {
    return std::forward<V>(v);
}

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(identity(42)), int&&>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(identity<int>(42)), int&&>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(identity<float>(42)), int&&>::value, "!");
    // here is the example mentioned by @Jarod42 in the comments to the question
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(identity<const int &>(42)), int&&>::value, "!");
}
```

This way, the return type depends on the actual type of the `v` parameter and you cannot *force* a copy in any way.

---

As mentioned in the comments by @bolov, the syntax could quickly become obscure.
Anyway, as suggested by @Jarod42, it's a matter of being more explicit about what we are doing.

As an example:

```
template <typename... EmptyPack, typename V, typename = std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(EmptyPack) == 0>>
```

As an alternative:

```
template <typename... EmptyPack, typename V, std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(EmptyPack) == 0>* = nullptr>
```

Or even:

```
template <typename... EmptyPack, typename V>
constexpr
std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(EmptyPack) == 0, V&&>
identity(V&& v) {
    return std::forward<V>(v);
}
```

Pick your preferred one up and use it, they should be all valid in this case.

Comment: And then the (troll) user: wtf this works: `identity<unsigned, long, long, int>(42ull)`. What is this syntax? :)

Comment: @bolov: so use `template <typename...EmptyPack, typename V, typename = std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(EmptyPack) == 0>` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9f0a0ad74f388d5)

Comment: @Jarod42 and where is the fun in that?